# remove php exentsion not working in .htacces

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, seo

I have a website, and the builder put in this code into my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]*)(\.php)?(\?*)$ index.php/$1$3 [L,QSA]
```

But, what i also need is:
- remove slash if it is no directory
- remove extension .php
- remove index.php if it is in de url

Ive tryed many suggestions, but i think it is in the code that is already in de .htaccess.

i've managed to redirect the site to www. if not given in the url

Does anyone have an idea? i'm out of ideas

Comment: You should include examples of incoming URLs to have an idea of what the rules are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before the rules that you already have, try adding these:

```
# remove trailing slash if not directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# remove index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\ /(.*)index\.php/?([^\?\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2 [L,R=301]

# remove php extension
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\ /(.*)\.php($|\ |\?)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: thanks, works! and if i want 1 directory with urls ( administration ) is that possible?